# MySQL SELECT using string based on data from another field

Tags: mysql, left-join, full-text-search, concatenation

This works:

```
SELECT `nid`, CONCAT('node/', `nid`) AS `vpath`, `title`
FROM `node` WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

So why doesn't this work:

```
SELECT `nid`, CONCAT('node/', `nid`) AS `vpath`, `title`, `alias`
FROM `node` WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
LEFT JOIN `url_alias` ON `url_alias`.`source` = `vpath`
```

Comment: What happens when you run the later version of SQL. Does it produce some error?

Comment: Nope, a different error. See my comment on that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JOINs should be placed before the WHERE statement.  Try:

```
SELECT `nid`, CONCAT('node/', `nid`) AS `vpath`, `title`, `alias`
FROM `node`
LEFT JOIN `url_alias` ON `url_alias`.`source` = `vpath`
WHERE MATCH(`title`) AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

[MYSQL Select Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Ah... although it's now saying "unknown column 'vpath' in 'on clause'".

Comment: Update: if I put the CONCAT('node/', `nid`) in the JOIN and omit the `vpath` all-together, it works. I don't know why using the column spits out an error though. Anyway, cheers!